# How to dynamically change the MS excel 2016 vlookup value by clicking on different cells?

Tags: vba, excel

Based on tables in an MS excel 2016 spreadsheet, I am working with a `sum` of `vlookup` array function in order to built the sum of two columns for a given lookup value:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_range, {2,3,4}, FALSE))
```

The tables typically look like this:

```
 Lookup_value       January February March  April
    8/15/2020       $1.66   $1.40    $1.05   $103.00 
    2/15/2021       $1.50   $1.97    $0.47  $99.51 
    8/15/2021       $1.50    $1.96    $0.46     $99.05 
    2/15/2022       $1.50    $1.95    $0.45     $98.60 
    8/15/2022       $1.50    $1.94    $0.44     $98.15 
    2/15/2023       $1.50    $1.93    $0.43     $97.72 
    8/15/2023       $1.50    $1.93    $0.43     $97.30
```

For example, the result of

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP( 8/15/2020, $A$1:$G$5, {January, March}, FALSE))
```

is $1.66 + $ 1.05 = **$ 2.71**

Is there a way to dynamically change the the lookup value by clicking on different cells? I need a tool which produces this vlookup sum for different date lookup values, defined when I click on them.

**How to dynamically change a vlookup value based on cursor operations?**

Comment: Did either of the below answers solve the issue? If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you rebuild the vlookup formula each time a user double-clicks, using a workbook event to monitor for clicks?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

Use these in the code for the 'ThisWorkbook' object. Then rebuild the vlookup using `ActiveCell.Address` or similar. Add to the vlookup each time the user double-clicks, and include a "Clear" button for resetting the vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formulas and VBA it would be much simpler to unpivot the data (using PowerQuery if you have it, or VBA if you don't), turn the data into a PivotTable, and then add a Slicer on the Month field. No VBA necessary, and the exact same outcome: someone clicks on the months they want, and the PivotTable shows the aggregations needed.